# Why is this has many relationship not updating its child model foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Model setup**

```
class Tiger < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mammal_tigers
  has_many :mammals, through: :mammal_tigers
  has_many :mammal_value_variants
  has_many :mammal_values, through: :mammal_value_variants

end

class Mammal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mammal_tigers
  has_many :tigers, through: :mammal_tigers
end

class MammalValueVariant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mammal_value
  belongs_to :variant
end

class MammalValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mammal_type
  has_many :mammal_value_variants
  has_many :variants, through: :mammal_value_variants
end
```

**association creation code:**

```
tiger = mammal_value.tigers.joins(mammal_tigers: :mammal).where(mammals: {id: mammal.id}).where(property_title: "#{mammal.property}-#{mammal_value.name}").first_or_create do |tiger|
  tiger.mammals << mammal
end
```

So when I run the association creation code above, any 'mammal.tiger_id' is nil.  Why is is the push operator not autosaving the foreign key on mammal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to break the block up, Rails' `first_or_create` only runs the block if the item isn't found.